# Инициализация static const струкруты внутри класса.

Tags: c++, структуры, namespace, c++14, инициализация

Доброго времени суток.

Есть класс со статическими полями который олицетворяет настройки. Внутри этого класса есть статик конст структура которая содержит в себе настройки по умолчанию. Как известно статические члены нужно инициализировать за пределами определения класса, но как это сделать с константной структурой?

Ниже представлена заготовка класса (хэдер и реализация).

//class.h

```
#ifndef BS_SETTINGS_H
#define BS_SETTINGS_H
#include <cstdint>
class BsSettings {
public:
    static void ResetToDefaultSettings();
    static uint8_t StationId;
    static uint8_t TcpServerIp[4];
    static uint8_t TcpBaseIp[4];
    static uint16_t TcpPort;
private:
    static const struct {
        uint8_t  TcpServerIp[4] = { 192,168,0,110 };
        uint8_t  TcpBaseIp[4] = { 192,168,0,115 };
        uint16_t TcpPort = 9005;
        uint8_t StationId = 22;
    } DefaultSetting;
};
#endif //BS_SETTINGS_H
```

//class.cpp

```
uint8_t BsSettings::StationId = 0;
uint8_t  BsSettings::TcpServerIp[4]{};
uint8_t  BsSettings::TcpBaseIp[4]{};
uint16_t BsSettings::TcpPort = 0;

void BsSettings::ResetToDefaultSettings() {
    memcpy(TcpServerIp, DefaultSetting.TcpServerIp, sizeof(DefaultSetting.TcpServerIp));
    memcpy(TcpBaseIp, DefaultSetting.TcpBaseIp, sizeof(DefaultSetting.TcpBaseIp));
    TcpPort = DefaultSetting.TcpPort;
    StationId = DefaultSetting.StationId;
}
```

P.S. Или еще можете подсказать как можно реализовать своё пространство имён внутри класса, что бы отказаться от структуры в этом, конкретном случае.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мало проку от такого класса со сплошь статическими полями. Сделайте обычный класс с конструктором по-умолчанию.

```
using
StationId = ::std::uint8_t;

using
Ip = ::std::array<::std::uint8_t, 4>;

using
Port = ::std::uint16_t;

class Settings
{
  private: StationId m_station_id;
  private: Ip        m_tcp_server_ip;
  private: Ip        m_tcp_base_ip;
  private: Port      m_tcp_port;

  public: explicit constexpr
  Settings(void) noexcept
  : m_station_id{22}
  , m_tcp_server_ip{192,168,0,110}
  , m_tcp_base_ip{192,168,0,115}
  , m_tcp_port{9005}
  {}

  // прочие конструкторы, геттеры / сеттеры...
};

constexpr Settings const default_settings{};

int
main()
{
   Settings settings{"config file path"}; // Допустим, инициализация из конфига
   settings.Set_Port(default_settings.Get_Port()); // сброс только одного поля
   settings = default_settings; // сброс всех полей
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне не хочется создавать объект, если я знаю что буду использовать эту сущность в одном экземпляре. За объектом надо следить а тут всё на уровне класса, очень удобный патерн (я часто применяю его в C#). Но вопрос был в том, как проинициализировать static const структуру внутри класса.

Comment: @mrFieldy Вам не хочется создавать объект и поэтому вы решили создать сразу 5 объектов? Кроме того, у меня есть подозрение, что вы тяните из C# некоторые ложные аналогии. Что вы подразумеваете под *"За объектом надо следить"*? Статическое поле внутри класса можно инициализировать только используя `constexpr` конструктор.

Comment: Наверное вы правы.

Answer (score 2):

Правильное решение, конечно, изменить класс, например как описано в ответе @VTT, но для протокола всё же отвечу на конкретные вопросы.

> Как известно статические члены нужно инициализировать за пределами определения класса, но как это сделать с константной структурой?

Можно просто инициализировать как обычную структуру в старом Си-стиле:

```
class BsSettings {
//...
    private:
    static const struct Settings {
        uint8_t  TcpServerIp[4];
        uint8_t  TcpBaseIp[4];
        uint16_t TcpPort;
        uint8_t StationId;
    } DefaultSetting;
};

//...

const BsSettings::Settings BsSettings::DefaultSetting = {
     { 192,168,0,110 },
     { 192,168,0,115 },
     9005,
     22
};
```

Замечание: структура не должна быть безымянной.

> Или еще можете подсказать как можно реализовать своё пространство имён внутри класса, что бы отказаться от структуры в этом, конкретном случае.

Можно определить структуру со статическими членами:

```
class BsSettings {
    //...
private:
    struct DefaultSetting {
        static const uint8_t  TcpServerIp[4];
        static const uint8_t  TcpBaseIp[4];
        static const uint16_t TcpPort;
        static const uint8_t StationId;
    };
};

//...

const uint8_t BsSettings::DefaultSettings::StationId = 22;
//...
```

Comment: Поля массивов компилятор вам не пропустит с таким синтаксисом. Я сделал такую же конструкцию через класс и инициализацию в cpp файле. Большое спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @mrFieldy, с массивами всё в порядке должно быть... а вот структура не должна быть безымянной, иначе тип при определении не указать (поправил)...

Comment: У вас было: 
  static const uint8_t  TcpServerIp[4] = { 192,168,0,110 };
внутри стукруты. Компилятор это не сможет сделать.

Comment: а... да, ошибка копипасты...